# List item with mouseenter

Tags: jquery

I want to create an effect where a user moves his mouse over an LI, a textarea inside of it will fadeIn, and when the user exists the LI the textarea will fadeOut. However, with the code I am attaching, it seems that once the user moves his mouse to the textarea, it fadesOut although it is part of the UL.

Demo is at http://jsbin.com/acaci3/4

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Caption</div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Caption</div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("ul li").hover(
     function() {
        $("textarea" , $(this)).fadeIn();
     },
     function() {
        $("textarea" , $(this)).fadeOut();
     }
  );
});
​
```

**CSS**

```
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  li {
    float:left; 
    width:800px;
    background:#ccc;
  }
  li div {
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    height:150px;
  }
  textarea {
    display:none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    resize: none;
    border: 3px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm viewing the demo in Opera, Firefox, IE and Chrome and it's working fine except for chrome.

Comment: It is completely flawless, you may have suspected because of u've used li very big one, i guess..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LYgfT/).

Note that it's using jquery 1.4.3

Comment: it's still the same as the OP FYI. ;)

Comment: Oh, now I just notice the issue in chrome. Working on it